# Is it possible to dropWhile on a FluentIterable?

Tags: java, python, guava, iterable

I would like to do something like python's dropwhile using Iterables in java.  Is it possible using FluentIterables?

dropwhile removes elements from an iterable until the first one that doesn't match and then returns all the rest of the elements.

I don't see an implementation like that in FluentIterable nor in Iterables.

Answer (score 0):

Guava does not currently (as of Guava 17.0) provide this functionality, but [Guava issue 477](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=477) is tracking this feature request.